# How to get Swashbuckle / Swagger working on the Mono (.NET) Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mono, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop I started a new WebApi project. The WebApi application is working as expected. In addition to the default WebApi project I added Swashbuckle / Swagger for auto-generating documentation of the API. When I navigate to swagger (http://localhost/swagger) an 404 error occured. In the documentation I found I need to add some configuration lines to the Web.Config.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
```

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/README.md#page-not-found-when-accessing-the-ui

After this change nothing changed. The project is running on the Mono XSP4 webserver. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/555#issuecomment-153493068

Add the following lines to your Web.Config file.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```